# Android use getSupportFragmentManager in Recyclerview Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i need to go to next `Fragment` if user clicks on a `Recyclerview` item. To do this i tried the following in my `Adapter`:

```
   viewHolder.getModel().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                seller fragment3 = new seller();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction3 = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction3.replace(R.id.fram, fragment3, "FragmentThree");  //create first framelayout with id fram in the activity where fragments will be displayed
                fragmentTransaction3.commit();
            }
        });
```

The problem now is that it cannot resolve `getSupportFragmentManager` what do i have to change?

Comment: how about send user to Activity which contains getSupportFragmentManager it will help you or interface between them ?

Comment: i dont know how to do that could you explain it more specific

Comment: My code is available in Kotlin so i can Just Guide you how to do it.

Comment: thanks for your help but i solved it using this line of code     ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager()
 thanks for your support

Answer (score 1):

I try to explain how to solve your problem with an interface. In your Adapter, you create an interface.

```
public interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClicked(int itemId);
}
```

After that, initialize the interface in the adapter class and add it to the cronstructor.

```
private ItemClickListener mListener;

public Adapter(ItemClickListener listener) {
    this.mListener = listener;
}
```

In your methode, you have to call the interface methode and pass the id.

```
viewHolder.getModel().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onItemClicked(getItemId);
        }
    });
```

Finally, you need to implement the interface in the activity or fragment of your recyclerview, in which you can access the fragmentmanager and pass it to the constructor of the adapter.

```
public class ExampleActivity extends  AppCompatActivity implement Adapter.ItemClickListener{

   Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this);

   //...

   @Override
   public void onItemClicked(int itemId) {
   // start fragment with the itemId 
   }
}
```